# Recover my iPhone 6s password

Tags: iphone

I have misplaced my iPhone 6s password and it is saying it's disabled due to too many tries.

Comment: You could take the SIM card out, it contains the passcode

Comment: @alex Not necessarily, the SIM passcode is different from the iPhone password.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your device needs to be erased by one of the following procedures

- If you've synced with iTunes, use iTunes.
- If you're signed in to iCloud and Find My iPhone is enabled, use iCloud.
- If you don't use iCloud and you can't sync or connect with iTunes, use recovery mode.

Apple has a support document describing the steps in detail, see [If you forgot the passcode for your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or your device is disabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306).

Answer (score -2):

1st way-

If your iPhone is connected to the internet, go to https://www.icloud.com/. Log in with your iCloud Id. Go to `Find My iPhone`, click on `My Devices` at the top middle of the screen. Click on your iPhone and click on the pop-up `Erase iPhone`. That should erase your iPhone and set it to the latest OS.

2nd way-

Download the latest iOS for your phone from [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-ios-9.3.4-ipsw-for-iphone-and-ipad-direct-links/). Connect your phone to your PC. Open up iTunes. `SHIFT` and `Click` on restore iPhone. Choose the downloaded `IPSW` file. Wait for iTunes to Erase your phone.

Comment: Why do you propose downloading iOS from a non-apple site in option 2? Erase and restore of the iPhone from iTunes is possible without this (potentially dangerous) step. Also, erasing it via Find My iPhone will do just that (erase), it will not update the OS or do anything else. So you still need to set it up again (via iTunes or iCloud, whereever your backup is stored) afterwards.